# Error message says "error" only

Tags: jquery, ajax

It's been a while I've been doing jQuery, so this might be a very basic question. I've done the following call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  success: function () { alert("hazaa"); },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#donkey").html(xhr.responseText + status + error);
  },
  type: "GET"
});
```

It gets executed but my *donkey* only shows the text *error* (*status* part, that is, while *xhr* and *error* are blank). I've tried to go *eval* on it but that caused an exception and nothing got done.

I've heard about this google site and it definitely is up and running, hehe. What did I miss?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access Google via AJAX because of the Same-Origin-Policy. See the "different host" example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Oh, now I remember - I've fought so much with it and used JSONP or something. Then we changed something on the server and actually allowed all connections or something. It was a lot of confused hacking back then... Is it still as painful or is there a smooth work-around?

Comment: I believe you can use CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for that.

Comment: I did that. There's a page that actually will do that work for you, as described in wikis here on SO as well (once I recalled the CORSish issues, the googling was a no-brainer, hehe). +1 for the link.